# Is there a way to get notified when device name in Android changes?

Tags: android, notifications

I want my app to receive a notification when the Android phone's name is changed. This is the name that can be found in Settings -> About Phone -> Device Name.

I have been looking into BroadcastReceiver to solve this, but haven't found any relevant ways to do so. Kindly help.

Comment: I don't think there is any way , Look at the broadcasts list https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/reference/broadcast-intents-30